# Regex for 2 numbers of the same length separated by dash

Tags: javascript, regex

What's the right regex for matching the following criteria:

- Two numbers, separated by a dash (-)
- Both numbers must have the same amount of digits, but at least 1 and not more than 5 digits
- before/after/between numbers and the dash there may be arbitrary whitespace

Examples that match:

- 123-444
- 1234 -  5678
- 98- 76

Examples that shouldn't match:

- 1234-567
- 123456-789012

Is such a thing possible?

Comment: Wel...[it can be possible](http://regex101.com/r/mA5uV4).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably you can use this:

```
^ *((\d *- *\d)|(\d{2} *- *\d{2})|(\d{3} *- *\d{3})|(\d{4} *- *\d{4})|(\d{5} *- *\d{5})) *$
```

#### Online Demo: http://regex101.com/r/jG0dB7

Comment: Does this allow for before/after numbers having whitespace?  For example `     123-321     ` ?

Comment: Yes it does allow 0 or more spaces on either side of hyphen. Check my linked demo.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't caught the left and right of the outer parenthesis allowing for the spaces.  Nice work, man!

Comment: How about spaces in between of numbers, such as "9 8-76" ?

Comment: @OmriAharon: I am not sure if that was really required by OP. It can be done by some tweaking though.

Comment: @Omri Aharon: No its not required. Only between numbers, not single digits

Answer (score 5):

**No**, this is not possible with regular expressions (at least, JS flavor). You can refer to already matched groups, but not to their properties (such as length).

Of course, with a max length limit, you can squeeze out an expression with all the possibilities, but even with the length 5 this would be an unmaintainable mess. Only imagine how silly it will get with the max len = 10. Therefore I'd suggest:

```
m = str.match(/^(\d+)\s*-\s*(\d+)$/)
valid = m && m[1].length == m[2].length
```

Comment: Also a very nice solution which can be easily adapted to arbitrary upper bounds for the number length!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
^ *((\d *- *\d)|(\d{2} *- *\d{2})|(\d{3} *- *\d{3})|(\d{4} *- *\d{4})|(\d{5} *- *\d{5})) *$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: How did you generate this diagram?

Comment: Full url to diagram: https://www.debuggex.com/i/ao3QAuNxpkdK9jt3.png