# JavaScript: How to get specific text in a string using RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex, string, photoshop-script

I tummbled into this RegEx and I googled it. A lot. But unfortunately didn't quite understand how RegEx works... 
So to make this quick since only a tiny winny part of my work requires it so I will be needing you guys. again :))

So here it goes...

All I want is to retrieve a specific string with a format of `0000x0000`. For example:

Input:`NameName975x945NameName`
Output:
`975x945`

Must also consider string like this: 
`NameNameName9751x9451NameNameName`
(the integer and string are longer...)

Comment: Using java or javascript?

Comment: Try `String output = input.replaceAll(".*?(\\d+x\\d+).*", "$1");`.

Comment: Regular expressions are very different between Java and JavaScript. Tag appropriately for the specific language.

Comment: @Mohammad Be **very** careful with edits. I think it's likely that the [tag:photoshop-script] was appropriate, and you introduced a misspelling in the headline.

Comment: It looks like you are looking for `\d+x\d+`. How to use this regex depends on language, so please specify that in your question/tags.

Comment: @chrylis That is right but what is relation of javascript/java with photoshop?!

Comment: @Mohammad Photoshop **Script**. Which can use JavaScript. Perhaps the OP is trying to manipulate EXIF information.

Comment: @Mohammad sorry for the confusion its JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use regex in [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to get specific part of string.

```
str.match(/\d+x\d+/)[0]
```

```js
var str = "NameName975x945NameName";
var match = str.match(/\d+x\d+/)[0];
console.log(match)
```

Comment: This works fine even if the digits length are not equal 'NameName1234x12NameName'  thanks for your help. '(Tried it here: https://regex101.com/r/WgakMg/1)'.  May I ask how this pattern works?

Comment: Why do you use `[]` in `/[\d]+x[\d]+/` is there any special reason?

Comment: @Mohammad what if I want to return the actual string it matches?

Comment: @Maguzu `[\d]+` match digits and `[\d]+x[\d]+` match two digits that `x` exist between of them.

Answer (score 0):

We need a bit more detail, but I'll go in order:

Assuming there can be any number of digits before and after the x, and these can be of different lengths:

`[\d]+x[\d]+`

Assuming the number of digits before the x needs to be equal to the number of digits after the x (as in your example) and this number is finite (and small enough so that your regex isn't obscenely long):

`[\d]{1}x[\d]{1}|[\d]{2}x[\d]{2}|[\d]{3}x[\d]{3}` (and so on)

Check out [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21088996/regex-for-2-numbers-of-the-same-length-separated-by-dash) for more details on handling this as the length of the number gets longer.

Then you can use `String.prototype.match()` with your regex to grab the matches within your string.

Comment: Emily, why you use `[\d]+x[\d]+` instead of `\d+x\d+`? Also why do you use `[\d]{1}`? isn't `\d` good enough?

Comment: Hi tried your but did match the digits with different length. https://regex101.com/r/ziSAxr/1